# Kill the [detect] and [detection] tags

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I saw the [detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detect) tag (683 uses) pop up today, and looking at the tag excerpt

> Detect relates to discover or identifying the presence of.

and the tremendous breadth of questions under it (hardware attached, hardware parameters, visitors on a webpage, language, ), it seems *way* overbroad and meaningless as a coherent thread of knowledge.

Also the [detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detection) tag (1006 uses...[maybe the scouter's upside down?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMc6pLdHx2k)) as nhahtdh points out. Specific detection tags are excellent ([device-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-detection), [face-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/face-detection), [browser-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser-detection)), and I would hope that by burninating detect/detection that people would tag their detection questions with the unequivocally superior alternatives.

KIWF?

Comment: It might be broad but is it used in a wrong/confusing/in contradiction with the tag description? For the few examples I looked at they didn't seem tagged wrong...

Comment: @rene: the tag description is useless. Who cares if it's being used consistently with vague nonsense, if it doesn't add anything to the site?

Comment: Agreed; in most of the questions I see, it usually just means that the goal is to get some information about something. You could probably phrase about half the questions on the site that way if you wanted; it doesn't mean they have anything in common, though!

Comment: Looks like a "tried to form a sentence with tags" tag to me. I vote for termination, with *extreme* prejudice.

Comment: I haven't seen the questions, and I am not against killing this tag, but I think there may be questions that can be retagged to appropriate [\*detect*](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/*detect*) tag. By the way, [tag:detection] can also be killed.

Comment: @nhahtdh agreed, detect/detection are uselessly vague and are too-easily misapplied (c.f. [like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like)), but feature-detection, device-detection, et al. are totally fine.

Comment: [tag:detect] now has a warning not to use it, but it is still used.

Comment: Someone create a burninate chat room where people can hang out and do these initiatives

Comment: "I [detect] this tag is worth burnination"

Comment: These are still around. Is there a way to revitalize this discussion?

Answer (score 4):

Currently there are 912 questions with the tag [detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detect) with a wiki saying that it is over broad and shouldn't be used

> "Detect" is overbroad and should not be used. Tag with the specific sort of detection you mean: collision-detection, face-detection, feature-detection, browser-detection, etc, etc.

The [detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detection) tag has 1625 questions with an even more vague wiki

> Detection is a general term that describes the action of finding an object, event or state during a process.

I don't see any differences for them to stay apart